# Cannot convert PSQL string to timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, psql

I am trying to do a simple string to date conversion; however, PSQL complains when there is a timezone in that string. Their documentation clearly states that its supported; however, it complains. I don't even care about the timezone, I just want to convert the string.

```
    db=> select to_timestamp('Mon Feb 23 13:43:07 PST 2015', 'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZ YYYY')::timestamp without time zone;

    ERROR:  "TZ"/"tz" format patterns are not supported in to_date
```

Postgres version: 9.3.10

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: almost the same issue
```select to_timestamp('2018-12-27 22:27:48 (-04)', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss TZH')::timestamp with time zone ```
 gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

Why not try a straight cast?

`SELECT 'Mon Feb 23 13:43:07 PST 2015'::timestamp with time zone`

Once you've done this it's pretty easy to work with the date object.